# What format does .getDay() accept?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Ok, so what I want to do is to retrieve some info from an `input` element, which is of `type` `date`. I then store this in a .json file, and I parse it later on to retrieve the data upon program start. After that, I want to use the `date.getDay()` function to figure out what day that date falls on.

I have only seen examples using `var d = new Date()`, and something tells me that the 'format' is different when using `new Date`than using `document.getElementById("dateInput").value;`

Anyone catch my drift? 
To sum up, I want to be able to find the day from the values outputted by an input `type = "date"` element.

Comment: Did you tried `new Date(<your_input_value>);` ?

Comment: You need to turn the input value (which is a string) in to a Date

Comment: Hmm.. I can try that now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Date.getDay()` does not accept the default type (**String**) that gets returned by the `elem.value()`-call.

**You have to pass a Date.**

So you can convert any legit string to a date using the "`new Date()`" constructor.

```
let dateString = "2018-03-08"
let dateFromString = new Date(dateString) // working
```

Please have a look at this example code:

```js
let date = new Date(mydate.value)
let day = date.getDay()
console.log(day)
```

```html
<input id="mydate" type="date" value="2018-03-08">
```

You could also find some helps in the docs:

- [Date JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)
- [JavaScript Date Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Well, `Date.getDay()` does not accept any input, it is an "instance method", if you will, of the `Date` class. This means a `Date` object must be instantiated before you can call `getDay()` on it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay

I think what you're trying to do is something along these lines:

```
<input id="js-date" type="date" value="2018-03-08">

let el = document.getElementById('js-date')
let date = new Date(el.value)
alert(date.getDay())
```